# Effectiveness of power training for bodybuilding

Tags: workout-routines

Does it really help to add a few sets of  power training exercises for bodybuilding workout?

Does it help in  building bulky muscles?

Is cheat curls a power training exercise for the biceps? 
If power training is useful  then any other power training exercises for the biceps?
I do 1)bench, deadlifts, squat, bent over rows
   2) heavy upright rows, push press, good mornings
 on alternate days.
I have just begun training (2 months).
Do you think it will be effective?

Comment: What do you mean by power training exercises? Do you mean explosive training, like plyometrics or speed-strength worth like the Westside Barbell Dynamic Effort Method?

Comment: In power training the emphasis is more on increasing and building strength rather than muscles . So here the reps usually are very less with very heavy weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just starting out, then it doesn't really matter if you take a powerlifting or bodybuilding approach. You'll be getting bigger and stronger regardless of which type of regimen you follow.

I'd say the question is premature. When you've been working out for a year or two, you can start deciding which branch to follow. For now, stick with whatever program you enjoy doing.